# Transfering file using tcp golang

Tags: go, tcp

I'm trying to make a music app that sends file through tcp protocol using go and microservice architecture. Now I'm creating a player service that should:

1. Get user token and get claims from it
2. Check is user exists using claims and user_service microservice
3. Get song from redis
4. Check is song exists using music_service
5. Read file by chunks and send it to client using tcp

Redis data looks like this:

```json
{
   "user_id": [{
                 "song_id": "<song_id>"
   }]
}
```

But I faced with a small problem. My music files stored in a flac format and when I receive it on the client, my player doesn't play it. I don't really know what can be the problem. So here's my code:

**SERVER**

*service_setup.go*

```golang
//this function is called in main function
func setService() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", config.TCPAddress)
    if err != nil {
        panic("couldn't start tcp server")
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            logger.ErrorLog(fmt.Sprintf("Error: couldn't accept connection. Details: %v", err))
            return
        }
        service.DownloadSong(conn)
    }
}
```

*downloader_service.go*

```golang
func DownloadSong(conn net.Conn) {
    token, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog(fmt.Sprintf("Error: couldn't get token. Details: %v", token))
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    claims, err := jwt_funcs.DecodeJwt(token)
    if err != nil {
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    songs, err := redis_repo.Get(claims.Id)
    if err != nil {
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    for _, song := range songs {
        download(song, conn)
    }
}

func download(song models.SongsModel, conn net.Conn) {
    filePath, err := filepath.Abs(fmt.Sprintf("./songs/%s.flac", song.SongId))
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog(fmt.Sprintf("Errror: couldn't create filepath. Details: %v", err))
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog(fmt.Sprintf("Errror: couldn't open file. Details: %v", err))
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    read(file, conn)
}

func read(file *os.File, conn net.Conn) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    buf := make([]byte, 15)
    defer conn.Close()
    for {
        _, err := reader.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
            logger.InfoLog(fmt.Sprintf("Details: %v", err))
            fmt.Println()
            return
        }
        conn.Write(buf)
    }
}
```

**CLIENT**

*main.go*

```golang
func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:6060")
    var glMessage []byte
    text := "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzYzlhNmE1OWI3ZmQyNTQ2ZjA4ZWEyYSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiMTIiLCJleHAiOjE2NzQyMTE5ODl9.aarSDhrFF1df3i2pIRyjNxTfSHKObqLU3kHJiPreredIhLNCzs7z7jMgRHQIcLaIvCOECN7bX0OaSvKdW7VKsQ\n"
    fmt.Fprint(conn, text)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    b := make([]byte, 15)
    c := 0
    for i, _ := reader.Read(b); int(i) != 0; i, _ = reader.Read(b) {
        c += i
        glMessage = append(glMessage, b...)
    }
    os.WriteFile("./test.flac", glMessage, 0644)
}
```

If you know what can be the problem, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: What is "stred"? Also, you really need to extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is stored there. I made a mistake

Comment: What is the difference between the files on source and target systems?

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences, but in target system the size of file is a little bit bigger than in source and hashes of files are also different

Comment: Log the bytes written and received and compare the two to further circle in on the problem.

Comment: You must not ignore the first return value of reader.Read because Read may return less than 15 bytes. That being said, you should just use `io.Copy(conn, reader)` in the server and similar on the client (io.ReadAll works too if you want to buffer everything in memory first).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to send the music file over the network in 15 byte chunks, which is likely not enough to play the song on the client side.

You can try increasing the chunk size, for example, to 8192 bytes. To do this, replace buf := make([]byte, 15) with buf := make([]byte, 8192).

Also, it's better to write the received data directly to the file rather than storing it in memory. You can do this by creating a file and using os.Create to write the received data to it:

```golang
file, err := os.Create("./test.flac")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: couldn't create file")
    return
}
defer file.Close()
for {
    i, err := reader.Read(buf)
    if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    file.Write(buf[:i])
}
```

I believe that this can solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. But I don't want to send all file, I just want to send it in parts. How can I do this?